How to make text bolder in flutter text widget
I am trying to make a text super bold, like very thick in my Widget tree.
Here is the code I have attempted:
Widget _buildWelcomeTitleWidget() {
    final titleTextStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyLarge!.copyWith(
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, // Not bold enough
          fontSize: 50,
          color: Colors.white,
        );
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: PlatformText(
        "welcome".tr(),
        style: titleTextStyle,
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

But it is not bold enough.
Meanwhile I am using the google_fonts package for my font which I have defined and attached to all widgets in my theme file as shown below:
 static final ThemeData themeData = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: LightTheme.backgroundColor,
    brightness: Brightness.light,
    primaryColor: AppTheme.primaryColor,
    primaryColorDark: AppTheme.primaryColorDark,
    cardColor: LightTheme.cardBackgroundColor,
    canvasColor: Colors.transparent,
    textTheme: GoogleFonts.ubuntuTextTheme()
        .apply(displayColor: Colors.black, bodyColor: AppTheme.gray900),
 ....

Is there another trick to get a super thick and very bold font applied to this particular welcome text widget that I may be missing?
Thanks for any ideas

I think that you may use Font Weight, like the follow example:
Text(
  'BOLDER',
  style: TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,
  ),
);


Yea, I tried that already and it's not bold enough

Try to add a border to the text, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html
